# Objective C: How can you pass integer variables between classes?

Tags: objective-c, variables, integer

So lets say I made a variable in one class called 'number' and gave it a value of 3.

and I made a variable in another class called 'number2'

what functions could I use to pass the value of 'number' to 'number2' in that other class?

Thanks.

Comment: I've added the "objective-c" tag and removed the "xcode" tag as this question is about the Objective C language without any specifics to the XCode development environment.

Answer (score 1):

To get started with Objective-C, including learning how to pass values as method arguments, have a look at Apple's [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html), [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html), and [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look up accessor methods on google.